# Scroll size changes while scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll, adapter

I have main.java

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);

        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

And CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    Context ctx;

    String[] items = {"123\n\n\n\n", "321\n\n", "111\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", "222\n", "333"};

    CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        ctx = context;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public enum RowType {
        TEXT_ITEM, HEADER_ITEM
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return RowType.values().length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {return items.length;}

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {return position;}

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {return position;}

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
                case 0: view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_text_item, parent, false);
                    break;
                case 1: view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_header, parent, false);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case 0: ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textItemTextView)).setText(items[position]);
                ((TextView) 
                break;
            case 1: ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.headerTextView)).setText(items[position]);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

list_view_text_item and list_view_header have different height.
And when I scroll down the list, scroll the slider to change the size.
Also I have this problem in PreferenceScreen.

Comment: The question is not very clear.